# Role of ribcage in benchpress

Tags: bench-press

In [this video](https://youtu.be/8l2hMp21poo?t=89) on benchpress self unrack by Kabuki strength, it is mentioned of "drawing the rib cage down" when self unracking. What exactly is meant by this, and how does this aid in the bench press?